# How to sum-up the last number/element in the list of tuples having multiple criteria?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop, tuples

samplelist = [('A', 'Pass', 10), ('A', 'Pass', 20), ('A', 'Failed', 5), ('B', 'Pass', 10), ('B', 'Pass', 5) ]

expected output = [('A', 'Pass', 30), ('A', 'Failed', 5), ('B', 'Pass', 15) ]

i used this code as my reference but still cant get it to work :

```
samplelist = [('A', 'Pass', 10), ('A', 'Pass', 20), ('A', 'Failed', 5), ('B', 'Pass', 10), ('B', 'Pass', 5) ]

i used this code as my reference but still cant get it to work :


from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(int)
for letter, value in samplelist:
    d[letter] += value
res = list(d.items())
print(res)
# expected output = [('A', 'Pass', 30), ('A', 'Failed', 5), ('B', 'Pass', 15) ]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since there are 3 elements in each tuple in the list, you need 3 variables to unpack those:

```
samplelist = [('A', 'Pass', 10), ('A', 'Pass', 20), ('A', 'Failed', 5), ('B', 'Pass', 10), ('B', 'Pass', 5) ]

from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(int)
for letter, status, value in samplelist:
    d[(letter, status)] += value
res = [key + (val,) for key, val in d.items()] # convert to required format
print(res)
```

Result:

```
[('A', 'Pass', 30), ('A', 'Failed', 5), ('B', 'Pass', 15)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You are having this issue because:

- Key to be formed is a combination of first and second items. You are not having the grouping key with just `letter` alone (which would also be throwing error at the front: `'too many values to unpack'`).

This can be solved more easier with a `groupby` with all the groups are seemingly adjacent:

```
[k + (sum(x[2] for x in g),) for k, g in groupby(samplelist, key=lambda x: x[:-1])]
```

**Code**:

```
from itertools import groupby

res = [k + (sum(x[2] for x in g),) for k, g in groupby(samplelist, key=lambda x: x[:-1])]
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer Austin.! :)